# Links broken in jekyll site

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

So I've been trying to get a jekyll generated site up on gh pages, but all the posts give me a 404 error.

I'm not sure why, the permalinks is set in the _config file and so there shouldn't be a problem, but when i navigate to the address pointed by the permalinks, its a 404.

Here's the source: 
[Meraki repo](https://github.com/achintp/meraki)

Any thoughts or solutions on this? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think where you have

```
baseurl: /meraki
```

should have an actual URL in it.

```
baseurl: http://achintp.github.io/meraki/
```